# Best Practices for Incorporating Project-Wide Definitions in Objective-C and iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In my case I have a highly customized iPhone app with all custom views. I'd like to take advantage of the iPhone 5 screen size, but my views require precise layout, and setting the autoresizingMask on my views is not sufficient.

I'd like to end up with some sort of project wide definition flag in each of my source files, and I would need to set this definition/flag at runtime. In my specific case, I could perhaps import some header file definition like this:

```
if ( IS_IPHONE_5 ) {

/* 
   Set appropriate frames for the additional screen space
*/
}

else {

/* 
  Set views otherwise
*/
}
```

This question isn't intended to be entirely subjective--it could apply to anyone looking to set and retrieve project wide definitions. Perhaps another case could be a color theme or something that could be changed in settings.

How do I set these definitions while my program is executing and how do I incorporate them across my source files?

Thank you.

Comment: To clarify - you want to know 1) how to check at run time if the device is an iPhone 5, and 2) how to make the function / method / macro that performs this check visible to all your source files. Is that correct?

Comment: I know I can check the if the device is an iPhone 5 via if ( [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height == 1136.0f ). So just how to make the function/method/macro visible across all source files. Thanks Carl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be as simple as putting a macro into your app's `APPNAME_prefix.pch` file:

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height == 568)
```

Every file in your application would be able to use it.

As an alternative suggestion, I think my preference would be to add a category on `UIDevice`, and perhaps also add a macro for convenience, and then have only the objects that needed it (i.e. objects in the view and controller layers responsible for layout) import it, to avoid coupling your model to `UIKit`.

For example, `UIDevice+iPhone5.h`:

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 [[UIDevice currentDevice] isIPhone5]

@interace UIDevice (iPhone5)

- (BOOL)isIPhone5;

@end
```

and `UIDevice+iPhone5.m`:

```
@implementation UIDevice(iPhone5Checking)

- (BOOL)isIPhone5
{
     return ([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height == 568); //or however else you want to check
}

@end
```

Whichever best suits your needs. Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a great answer Carl, thanks. To wrap this up, your solution answers my immediate question, but what about some define that could be changed, like my theoretical example of a color theme? In that case each controller would need to look and see which color theme was currently set. No pLists. Ideas?

Comment: @Monticello Thank you! Glad you found it useful. I think this approach can generalize to many other situations. Find or create an object that best fits with the responsibility you are assigning to it. Perhaps in your color example, maybe it doesn't make sense for the view controllers to be aware of a theme so much as you provide a `UIColor` category with a number of convenience methods, and every controller knows what color name goes with what. e.g. provide a `+headerBackgroundColor` method, which would return different `UIColor` instances based on the current color theme. cont'd...

Comment: I'm a big proponent of only importing the minimum, so I would just import the files in the views and controllers that are responsible for  assigning colors to UI elements. But if you want global visibility, again put the category import in your `.pch` file. For convenience in your category header also provide a number of `#define`s e.g. `#define HEADER_BACKGROUND_COLOR [UIColor headerBackgroundColor]`. Does this all make sense? The general principle is assign sensible, project wide behaviors and responsibilities to appropriate classes cont'd...

Comment: Whether you create these classes yourself, or add them as categories on framework classes, is dependent on the nature of the task at hand. Oh, and another tip on visibility - if you are using say a generic superclass of `UIViewController` for all your app's controllers, then if you're not using the `.pch` I'd say put the color import in the superclass header for easy use by subclasses. Anyways I hope that's given you some direction on the more general case. Please let me know f I can expand some more.

Comment: And finally - you mention a constraint on color theme storage that plists are not allowed. I think that's more of an implementation detail to be handled by whatever class or category is involved in implementing the features. Hope this all is helpful to you!

Comment: Your class category suggestion has got me thinking in the right direction. In theory, after changing something that should be reflected across all controllers (like a color theme change), one could have each controller call something like 
    `reloadViewColors`
and look to a `UIColor` category for the appropriate one:
    `UIColor *new = [UIColor myAppNameRedColor];`

Your suggestions have been very helpful. Cheers.

Comment: @Monticello sounds like a great plan! Glad I could help.